# Is there any evidence that other browsers will support Google Chromes drag download to desktop?

Tags: html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

Does anyone know when or if other browsers like Firefox and IE will allow users to download files from their browser using drag and drop like Google Chrome?

This feature is super cool and I wish I could use it in all browsers!

Thanks, Ian

UPDATE:
Here is an example:

```
    ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('DownloadURL', 'application/force-download:[FILENAME]:[PATH TO FILE]);"
```

Comment: Not entirely sure of what you mean. Could you give an example of using this feature?

Comment: @zeel I added an example of the feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell this is a Chrome feature, and not part of the Drag and Drop specification. My research also suggests that Google only even added it so they can use it with there products (Gmail, and probably the new google drive).

As this is not a part of the Drag and drop specification, and neither Mozilla nor Microsoft have announced anything about it, I believe the answer is no. However if it becomes a popular feature others may follow suit.

It may also be possible to emulate the effect with more complicated code (drag and drop is there, this specific feature is not) or perhaps with a browser add-on.